# Saving the code of a ticket unhashed

Tags: hash

I am making a simple ticketing system for a small local party so people can order their tickets for the party online.

It works like this:

1. The user enters his info.
2. He pays for the ticket.
3. If the payment was successful a unique `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` string is generated for the ticket.
4. The user gets a mail with a QRCode containing the unique string.
5. On entrance the QRCode gets scanned, if the ticket matching the code is paid, entrance is granted.

I am rewriting an old system of mine. In my old system I would generate the `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` and save the **hashed** version in the database. Before I hash it, I would generate the QRCode and save it as JPEG on my server and the image of the QRCode is sent to the user.

But now, to simplify things, I do not hash the random string and just retrieve it unhashed from the database and generate the QRCode on the go. This way I do not need to save a lot of JPEG's on my server.

Is it a huge security-risk to save the unhashed versions? Is there a better way to do it more secure without saving a ton of JPEG's?

Comment: It is not clear from your question why you need  to keep the original values (either directly or as image) at the server in the first place.

Comment: The user actually accesses his ticket by clicking on a link which leads to a page containing the QRCode. So I need to be able to load the original value.

Comment: Since the user is able to access the ticket with the link you could also encode the ticket value in the link and generate the QR code on the fly - no need to store the image on the server. If you want to ensure that the value in the link is valid before generating the image just hash it and check it against the hashed value in the database.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a huge security-risk to save the unhashed versions?

In both cases you describe you store the original value on the server - either directly or QR encoded. So a difference in security would only exist if the value in the database would be somehow easier to obtain for an attacker than the QR encoded value in the image - which is unknown.